# Is there a way to include one xaml page as a part into another?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to make a page comfortable for portrait and landscape. So, in portrait it will have two separate pages, in landscape - two frames where first and second pages will be visible at the same time. So, is there a way to implement it? I mean xaml and code behind.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're looking to display one page at a time in portrait and two pages side-by-side in landscape?

Comment: Yes, in general. There is a few second page types, so it's not fit the idea of pivot/panorama.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A XAML page can be included in another one just like any other control.

```
<Page x:ClassName="MyUberMetaPage" ...>

    <Grid ...>

        <local:MyPage1 x:Name="LeftPage" Grid.Column="0" />
        <local:MyPage2 x:Name="RightPage" Grid.Column="1" />

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

In MyUberMetaPage's code-behind you'll want to show/hide things as necessary based on window size, or more likely, dynamically create LeftPage and RightPage and add them to the UI (so you aren't constructing pages and then not actually showing them).

Comment: No, each XAML file will have its own .xaml.cs code-behind file; each XAML file represents a different class.  So in this example, MyUberMetaPage, MyPage1, and MyPage2 are all independent classes and will each have their own code-behind.